# convert rails app from 3.0 to 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails 3 application on localhost, but my host (dreamhost) uses 2.3.5.

Are there any techniques to downgrade my application?

I've tried installing rails 3 locally, but there is a conflict with rake.  And simply trying to run my application results in an "uninitialized constant Bundler" error.

I'd rather not re-write it from scratch, so if anyone has any tips for conversion, that would be awesome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be painful to "downgrade" a Rails 3 application but it might be feasible by simply creating a new one with the target version of Rails, then:

- copy your tests from the Rails 3 project
- copy code from to make them pass
- repeat as necessary

Why is Dreamhost not able to host a Rails 3 project? When you do `bundle install` all your gems should be installed, including the proper version of Rails.

Comment: the biggest problem is dreamhost uses passenger, and runs rack 1.1.0, and rails 3 requires rack 1.2.1, so you get an error when you try to run any rails 3 application with passenger.  They dont allow WEBrick. Thanks for the advice, i was hoping there was an easier way.